# create log for an encrypted tar

Tags: logging, redirect, encryption, openssl, tar

I want to create an encrypted tar but also I want to have a log of what tar has compressed, I'm using the following command:

```
tar -cvvf - --files-from=/root/backup.cfg | openssl des3 -salt -k backuppass | dd of=/root/tmp/back.encrypted
```

But I need to have a log of tar's stdout. I don't know how to get it, because If I use ">" in tar command openssl result is not correct.

I've also checked tar manual hoping to find some option to write stdout to a file, but I have found nothing.

any help?

thanks & Regards.

Comment: btw. the pipe to dd is unnecessary. You can just direct stdout to a file `> /root/tmp/back.encrypted`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thx for this question, I didn't know how tar behaves in that situation. It seems to me, that in case the archive is stdout, tar outputs all other information on stderr. So here you go for logging to backup-tar.log:

```
tar -cvvf - --files-from=/root/backup.cfg 2>backup-tar.log | openssl des3 -salt -k backuppass | dd of=/root/tmp/back.encrypted
```

Comment: thanks! thats what I need, but there is a parameter that is also useful "--totals". This parameters let me see the total size:
Total bytes written: 22732800 (22MiB, 17MiB/s)